# Convert Words in a string to sentence case for german sentences

Tags: c#

I am searching for a way to change the words in a String to SentenceCase.
I know the Method `TextInfo.ToTitleCase` but this is not working the right way for german. Like in the documentation of the Method:

```
Input                            Language    Expected result                   Actual result
Per anhalter durch die Galaxis   German      Per Anhalter durch die Galaxis    Per Anhalter Durch Die Galaxis
```

Is there another way to convert this right (get the expected result)? The verbs and adjectives should be in lower case.

There are a lot of question but I have not found one which is working the correct way with german.

**edit:**

I have tried

```
var ti = new CultureInfo("de-DE", false).TextInfo;
var res = ti.ToTitleCase("Per anhalter durch die Galaxis");
```

res is know

```
Per Anhalter Durch Die Galaxis
```

Comment: That's called a dictionary. You want all nouns to be capitalized.

Comment: Can you update the question and post your code?  Have you tried setting the culture explicitly for German?  Something like this:  
      TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-DE",false).TextInfo;

Comment: 'Converts the specified string to title case (except for words that are entirely
 in uppercase, which are considered to be acronyms).' I dont think your expectation is correct, it is behaving as it should. It doesn't discern between types of words.

Answer (score 1):

You want to fix the casing for the [German display of nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization#Nouns), and nouns only. There's no built-in functionality in .NET for that. The method you chose, `TextInfo.ToTitleCase()`, is too "dumb" for that as it'll simply uppercase the first letter of each word.

As far as I know, you're going to need Natural Language Processing for that. A dictionary won't cut it, because there are words that can be interpreted both as a noun (should be capitalized) and a verb (shouldn't be capitalized).

Or, to put it in other words (and ignoring the noun part for a minute): when you encounter "sie", how do you know whether "they" ("sie") or "you", formal ("Sie") is meant?

You could give it a try though, with a naive approach that won't yield perfect but maybe acceptable results:

Preparation:

1. Obtain a dictionary file of all German words
2. Strip it so only nouns remain

Code:

1. Split your input on word boundaries
2. Match each word against your dictionary
3. Uppercase the first letter of the word if it's a hit
4. Reassemble the input

Answer (score 1):

`ToTitleCase` simply and naively changes the case of each word in a string so that the first letter of a word is uppercase. The culture info will be used to determine what counts as a first letter to a word (such as what symbols/punctuation separate words), but it's not for determining which words of the given language should (not) be titlecased.. You'll need to roll your own solution for this level of language understanding